# MediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync crashes with many static images

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app that renders .gif files to .mp4, using the Windows.Media.Editing.MediaComposition class.

Certain files will randomly crash the RenderToFileAsync method. There are at least two different error messages you can receive, one stating insufficient memory.

Does anyone have any ideas for a workaround, or some insider knowledge on how this is supposed to work?

Repro:

- Create new c# WP8.1 Silverlight app blank project in VS2013
- Add Usings and OnNavigatedTo to MainPage.xaml.cs as below.
- Run in 512MB emulator. Observe crash (most of the time). Fiddle with value of i to see it work properly.

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Navigation;
  using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
  using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
  using System.IO;
  using Windows.Media.Editing;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  ```

-

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsIndeterminate= true;
    var comp = new MediaComposition();
    var r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 190; i++)
    {
        var wb = new WriteableBitmap(576, 300);

        for (int iPix = 0; iPix < wb.Pixels.Length; iPix++)
        {
            wb.Pixels[iPix] = r.Next();
        }

        string filename = "file" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
        var file = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (var curr = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            wb.SaveJpeg(curr, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 95);
        }

        var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(file, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(60));
        comp.Clips.Add(clip);
    }

    // Ensure add capability to write to video library AND ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO and change below to 
    // Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.VideosLibrary to see output in Videos app
    var destFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var destFile = await destFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.mp4", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    Debug.WriteLine("Mem use before render to disk: " + Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsage.ToString("N0"));
    await comp.RenderToFileAsync(destFile);
    Debug.WriteLine("Mem use after render to disk: " + Windows.System.MemoryManager.AppMemoryUsage.ToString("N0"));

    SystemTray.ProgressIndicator.IsVisible = false; 
    MessageBox.Show("Done OK");

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code through the Windows Phone application analysis memory profiler. I can confirm that your app is running into the system memory limit of about 150 MB. The MediaComposition engine can require large amounts of memory depending on the size of the input and output formats. In your case you are adding a large number of clips. The number of clips that can be added is limited by the memory available for the decode.

Quite honestly the MediaComposition was not designed to handle such a large number of clips. The expected average number of clips hovers around five.

Unfortunately I was not able to get the only possible workaround I could think of to work. I think that this solution might be feasible but unfortunately I can't spend any more time on it: You might be to create multiple output files using lower numbers of clips. For instance you could create an output file with images one through twenty. You could then create a second file with images twenty one through forty. You could then join these two files together.

I hope this helps,

James

Comment: Thanks. I already considered that workaround but couldn't be bothered implementing it. Is there anywhere in the documentation that states that it's not designed to handle this number of clips? Why would there be a limit anyway if it's streaming from and to disk? The documentation around MediaComposition in general is really very sparse. I made the above more reliable by specifying the output type/bitrate etc. Found out the hard way that output width/height must be multiples of 2, another thing that appears undocumented :(

Comment: Here are the answers to your questions: 1) The documentation is not clear on how the API handles large timelines. 2) The media is not streamed from disk as you might think. This is due to the fact that the API must hold roughly the buffer window plus the keyframe interval in memory to be able to transcode. All of the clip objects also offer large amounts of overhead. That said I'm working with the MSDN folks to get the documentation updated.

Comment: Hi, can you please also update the documentation for MediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync(), I am getting many reported exceptions in my (different) app when using a timeFromStart that is between zero and the composition duration. The two exceptions I get are: Thumbnail timeFromStart is outside of the composition bounds: 808260000 and System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. What are the rules around the start and end parameters you pass to this method?? Documentation is non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

I had basically the same problem and after much trial and error I finally got rid of my "Value does not fall within the expected range" error which caused many or all missing frames.

I added GC.Collect(); right before every MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync. It doesn't seem to effect performance or cause any problems and was the only way I could fix it. Hope this can help others.

Here is some of my code so you can see what I'm talking about:

```
foreach (var thisFrame in frames)
{
        GC.Collect();
        try
        {
               MediaClip clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(thisFrame, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(36 * speed));
               app.mediaComposition.Clips.Add(clip);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
               Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
}
```