# Creating a video from a collection of BitmapImage in UWP

Tags: c#, video, uwp, windows-10-desktop

I'm trying to come up with a method of creating a video file (or even an animated gif), using a collection of `BitmapImage` in a Windows 10 application (UWP).  I noticed that the mobile extensions have a ScreenCapture class (I'm not sure if that would do what I need anyway), but I need this to work on desktop as a minimum.  I've had a play with the `MediaCapture` class, but am unable to find any methods that allow me to record images from the screen, or manipulate the video directly.

```
Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture mc = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture();
mc.StartRecordToStreamAsync()
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible using UWP in C#, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need [MediaComposition API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition.aspx).

```
var composition = new MediaComposition();
```

Add clips ([files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.editing.mediaclip.createfromimagefileasync.aspx))

```
composition.Clips.Add(await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(someImageFile));
```

and in the end [render to file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn652696.aspx)

```
await composition.RenderToFileAsync(file);
```

Comment: @igor When I have many images, MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync throws some randomly system.argument errors. Cannot create Clip. 
Here it shows another error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341312/mediacomposition-rendertofileasync-crashes-with-many-static-images

Do you have any idea how to fix it?